# LDAPConnection with Certificate Excample

Tags: c#, ssl, ldap, x509certificate

I struggle with LDAPConnection. Does anybody has a good example on how to use LDAPConnection properly? Google doesnt give me something I could work with.

I need to open e LDAP-Connection using SSl and having a Certificate + PW.

```
// options

string sServer = "LDAP://192.168.50.147:636/dc=data,dc=vzd";

// ldap

LdapDirectoryIdentifier ldapIdent = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(server: "192.168.50.147", portNumber: 636, fullyQualifiedDnsHostName: true, connectionless: false);
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(myUserName, myCertificate);

// ldap connection
        
LdapConnection ldapConn = new LdapConnection(ldapIdent);
ldapConn.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
ldapConn.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
ldapConn.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };
ldapConn.ClientCertificates.Add(clsGlobal.TI_Steuer.certX509);
ldapConn.Bind(netCred);

// query

string sQueryFormat = "(&(sn=*e*))"
```

My questions are:

1. How do I exactly connect to "LDAP://192.168.50.147:636/dc=data,dc=vzd"?
2. How do I attach Certificate + Certificate-PW with SSL to that Request?
3. How do I add a SearchQuery?
4. How do I get the LDAP's answer?

Thanks in advance. I appreciate every help.

Comment: What happens when you run the code you have?

Comment: It says in the exception that the Server doesn't function properly :(

Comment: What is the exact error message?